# Is it possible to mock an approval process through Apex?

Tags: apex, unit-test, approval-process, mock

I have a generic piece of code that is responsible of approve a record. It does not assume the SObject type nor the process definition.

For example, something like the following:

```
public static Boolean approveRecord(Id recordId, String comment, User nextUser) {
  ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItemId = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
    WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :recordId
  ];

  Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest appRequest = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
  appRequest.setComments(comment);
  appRequest.setAction('Approve');
  appRequest.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{nextUser});
  appRequest.setWorkitemId(workItemId.Id);
  Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(appRequest);
  return result.isSuccess();
}
```

I want to test this piece of code without losing generability. It was already asked on salesforce.SE [how to create an approval process definition programmatically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224531/how-do-you-create-an-approval-process-programatically) within test classes without success. My thought is that maybe is possible to mock the behavior.

Comment: selector and service classes; then apexmocks would be an approach. See Fawcett's _Salesforce Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture, 3rd edition_

Comment: @cropredy I had a look at Andy's approach. It's really interesting but I think that is a bit overkill to implement it just for this one case. Also, it's still not very clear how could I be able to mock it even by using it.